# How to show haystack query in a different page?

Tags: django, django-views, django-haystack

I've read the getting started Haystack documentation but I'm really struggling in how to pass the queryset results to a separate page. I've several days trying but without any results.

I've created my own view and form for the search. I called them in the search.html template and they are working ok if show the results in there. But, what I don't is how to pass all the results to the results.html template.

Could you help me define how to receive the parameters in the results view. I'll appreciate so much.

views.py

```
class InstitutionSearchView(SearchView):
    __name__ = 'InstitutionSearchView'
    template = 'search/search.html'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Needed to switch out the default form class.
        if kwargs.get('form_class') is None:
            kwargs['form_class'] = InstitutionSearchForm

        super(InstitutionSearchView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


def search(request):
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('type_institution').facet('levels').facet('languages').facet('location')
    form = InstitutionSearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data

    return InstitutionSearchView(form_class=InstitutionSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs)(request)


def results(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render_to_response('search/results.html', locals(), 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^$',  views.search, name='haystack_search'),
    url(r'^results',  views.results, name='results'),)
```

search.html

```
<div class="span12">
    <h1>Search</h1>
     <form method="get" action="{% url 'institution:results' %}" class=".form-search">
        <table>
           {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

results.html

```
{% if query %}
 results
{% endif %}
```